# How to pass URL Parameters through a .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess

I need to transparently pass a URL parameter through a .htaccess 301 redirection but I am unfamiliar with how to code it.

For example, an Adwords clickthrough appends the following parameter to the landing page url:
    &gclid=CKCPq62Sq6wCFY1S4god4FZd1g

Our Google landing page is being redirected like this: 
Redirect 301 /old-page /new-page

(We don't want to edit our Google Ads as doing so would lose our existing stats. Thus the redirect..)

How do I preserve the above gclid parameter while redirecting in .htaccess?

Thanks,
Geoff

Answer (score 0):

You can't handle dynamic query strings properly with standard htaccess 301 redirect. In order to do so you should use mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule /old-page /new-page?%{QUERY_STRING} [R=301,L]
```

See, http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html

NOTE: I'm not positive that RewriteCond is required, but it's there to prevent the page from redirecting over and over again. Depending on the rest of the layout of your site, you may need it... although in most cases it's not needed unless you're redirecting all requests.

Comment: The above doesn't seem to work.  According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3817729/301-htaccess-rewriterule-query-string , RewriteCond is required?

Comment: RewriteCond is not required in all cases I don't believe. RewriteCond is an option which you can use if you want to add additional match conditions to the RewriteRule below it. You can use multiple RewriteCond's in a row if you want, they all apply to the first RewriteRule below it.

Comment: @Geoff, i have edited my answer though, because there is one RewriteCond that should be used in this case. My apologees I wrote the code off memory.

Comment: @Geoff, i honestly don't think the rewritecond is necessary... if you're still having troubles try pasting your entire htaccess and example URLs.